# Higher speed website caused adsense RPM to go zero. why?

Tags: seo, links, forms, post

I modified my website slightly so that links pointing to an item submission of some sorts (such as the "add item to shopping cart" link) are now submit buttons. For example:

I converted:

```
<a href="http://example.com/item123/buy">Add to cart</a>
```

To something like:

```
<form action="example.com" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="ItemNo" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="buy">
</form>
```

This comes with two advantages. The button click doesn't go to a cached page, meaning data is actually being submitted, and seeing that I've applied this change to over 500,000 pages and I changed 4 links to 4 buttons, Search engine spiders will now have to only scan 500,000 pages as opposed to 2,500,000 pages.

The only thing I can think of which might be a problem is ads inside those pages after the button is clicked.

So now I'm curious. I looked at my performance stats, and my RPM was averaging out at 7 cents RPM and now today after the change its at 0 cents RPM. I know people say that RPM means that's what you make per 1000 users, but I think google is evaluating it much differently.

So can anyone tell me why my RPM went to 0 and/or give me suggestions on how to increase my RPM without forcing users to require the use of javascript to view my site? Is my form at fault? could my link idea be improved? I apparently am terrible at SEO's best practices.

Comment: RPM is calculated over the past 30 days. This means that realistically, it cannot have actually gone down to 0 overnight. It is a metrics/calculation snafu of some sort and I will bet you that it will correct itself in time. I am sure it is just a coincidence. On a side note, $.07 is rather low. But being an e-commerce site, I rather suspect your focus has not been on Adsense conversion. If this is an important part of your strategy, then you must focus your SEO to: one, gain user traffic; and two, focus more on "money" keywords. I do not know your site, but I am sure it can be improved.

Comment: "seeing that I've applied this change to over 500,000 pages and I changed 4 links to 4 buttons, Search engine spiders will now have to only scan 500,000 pages as opposed to 2,500,000 pages." - how many pages (canonical URLs) do you have on your site? If you have 500,000 pages then search engines can only ever scan 500,000 pages, regardless of internal linkage? (It sounds like you are implying that spiders literally crawl links as they find them? - that is not how search engine spiders work.)

Comment: I did the changes to try to focus more on seo (hence trying to make spiders crawl 2,000,000 less pages and trying to make them crawl the more useful pages). Each of the pages is focused on a different image. And even if search engines dont crawl every link they find, I'm sure content scrapers try to crawl every link in every anchor tag and by me making the changes, I'd at least gain speed (by giving content scrapers less links to crawl). But I do appreciate closetnocs answer. maybe time is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using POST to pass relevant parameters to the page such as what was added to the cart, AdSense no longer knows what is on the page.   From [Ad code implementation AdSense code for dynamically generated pages](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2806011?hl=en):

> *Dynamic pages that use the POST method for form submission*
>   Sites using the POST method use the same URL for many different content pages. To allow us to target the content of each unique page, we recommend that you change these pages so that your variables are passed through the URL using the GET method.

This will either cause ads not to display at all, or to not be relevant to the content of the page.

Comment: Ok, funny thing is today I received an adsense click from the page with 4 buttons on a post form. The content when the post form is submitted doesn't qualify as a full page because its pretty much a repeat of the previous page but with a status message added. so I guess I made the right move.